# SQL Server display server name other than connected one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2` to do my project.

I noticed that the when I execute following code:

```
print @@SERVERNAME
```

I've got a output `"Server-01"`. However, I am actually connecting to `"Server-03"`, and the above code is executed in `"Server-03"` as well.

So, may I know what cause such strange output? What is the mechanism behind this?

Thanks.

Comment: It means someone hasn't followed the advice on [Rename a computer that hosts a standalone instance of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143799.aspx) having either renamed the server or restored an image originally taken from `Server-01`.

Comment: SELECT serverproperty('MachineName')

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the wrong name because someone renamed this server after SQL Server was installed (possibly, it's been imaged as a SQL Server installation) and they've not followed the correct advice to get SQL Server's internal information updated after they did the renaming.